flex container has extra bottom gap when a card-body is inside, and container of the .row has fixed height
I have 5 cards which have display as flex in a row with class mrow.I have the row in a container with class mcontent.The height of the row is 571px.
.mrow{height:100%}
.mcontain{height:571px}

But when I have a button in 3rd flex, it gets extra space below it and expands the entire row. I tried adding align-self: flex-start; as stated here but in vain.
My actual result is

second row height is lower than first

This is where I added my align-self code but it doesn't remove the bottom space

Thanks in advance
Edited to add:
when I run $(".mrow").css("height", ' calc(100% - ' + (- (-$(".div_text_center").height())) + 'px)'); the height increases for every card creating an extra space below ( below only 1 card. I want all cards same height). How do I overcome it?
Edited to add:
In maximised mode, the first row with 3 cards has height greater than second row with remaining 2 cards after the button is added.
That is my problem. I need both the 2 rows same height even when button is added in 3rd card of my first row


function relocate() {
                    $(".mcontain").css("height", ' calc(100% - ' + ($(".navbar").height() - (-$("footer").height()) - (-$(".div_text_center").height())) + 'px)');
                    $(".mrow").css("min-height", ' calc(100% - ' + (- (-$(".div_text_center").height())) + 'px)');
                    //$(".mcardlogin").css("min-height","200px");
                }
                relocate();
.mcontain{
  height:571px;
}.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex
;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
main, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    /* margin: 0; */
}
.mrow {
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% + 0px);
    
}
.row{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}
.card-header {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
.card1 {
    background-color: violet !important;
}
.card2 {
    background-color: indigo !important;
}
.card3 {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
.card4 {
    background-color: green !important;
}
.card5 {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
.mcardlogin {
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.a_login {
    float: right;
}
.colorwhite {
                    color: white;
                }
.a_button {
                    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f, 0 0 30px #00f;
                    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f, 0 0 30px #00f;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #00f, 0 0 30px #00f;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 28px;
                    border-radius: 28px;
                    background: #168bff;
                    display: block;
                    
                    padding-top: 20px;
                    padding-bottom: 20px;
                    margin: 20px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font: bold 17px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-align: center
                }

                    .a_button:hover {
                        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #f00, 0 0 30px #f00;
                        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #f00, 0 0 30px #f00;
                        box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #f00, 0 0 30px #f00;
                        background: #f56565;
                    }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="container mcontain" style="">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3 m_main">
  <div class="mrow row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mcardlogin card1">
                  <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="right">
                            <div class="min250px">
                                <div id="divtick_login" class="logininfo" style="display: none;">
                                    <i class="bi bi-check-circle green loginwrong"></i>
                                    Welcome,
                        <i id="sessionuser"></i>
                                    <a class="a_logout">Logout</a>

                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                    <div id="divwrong_login" class="logininfo">
                        <i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle red logintick"></i>
                        Logged out
                        <a class="a_login">Log In</a>
                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mcardlogin card2">
<div class="card ">
</div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mcardlogin card3">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="right">
                            <div class="min250px colorwhite">
                                Details
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text"><a class="a_button" >go</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mcardlogin card4">
                <div class="card ">
                  </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mcardlogin card5">
                    <div class="card ">
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>



JSFiddle

The increased height of that row appears to be due to the <br /> you placed before that button ...?

@C3roe it removes upper gap when I remove the <br/> in Inspect element . Lower gap remains same. (Check the link I have given, sign up there, it will change the heights)

If you are referring to https://5050customers.ct.ws/ - that looks nothing whatsoever like what you presented here in this question for me, not even close, and I have no idea what you mean by "sign up there" either.

@C3roe sign in with your mail (click login and google one-tap appears, click continue. it changes first card text to "welcome"), and a button appears in the 3rd card, and makes first row higher than second row

No, I am not going to sign up anywhere externally. Present your problem properly inside the question. And properly explain, what exactly the issue is supposed to be! You have modified the snippet here in the question in the meantime, so it doesn't look even close to the image you have shown as "My actual result is" any more.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Do you want that "Go" button next to the "Details" text, same as with the "Log in" in the first column?

@C3roe no, I have added a bigger full screen output in question please check. This is my problem: when I have no "Welcome" text and "Go" button, the two rows are of same height. When I add the "go" button, the first row is higher than second. The "Go" button should be in the 3rd card only. No change in it

Neither the snippet in the question, whether in "small" or in fullscreen mode, nor the jsfiddle you linked to, actually reproduce what you screenshot shows.

@C3roe Ok working on it

@C3roe Hi,I'm back. Please check new snippet full screen result and jsfiddle full screen result.

Why is this still using such an outdated Bootstrap version? In v3, the column classes are still using float, and the rows aren't flexbox containers to begin with, you are adding that via your own mrow class. It looks like you are still pretty much in the early stages of setting this whole thing up - so why not use a current Bootstrap version?

@C3roe Hi I'm back. I have used latest bootstrap. But the first row height is greater than second. Is it correct ?

You're putting the card class on the columns there, which is probably not a good idea. Put the cards into columns, as shown here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/card/#using-grid-markup, and see what result that gets you.

@C3roe Hi I'm back I tried it and the div's height is growing yet, when I give fixed height for row. So I gave height to col also as 200px. But I tried it as min-height. It's working fine now.
